# What is the difference between CartesianObjectLen and ObjectLen in MapInfo?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo

I'm a little unsure, which one is closer to calculating length using "Calculate Geometry" in ArcMap?

Comment: This question was flagged as low-quality because of its length.  You could easily add more details to it like links to the relevant MapInfo and ArcGIS help, and/or some quotes of key information from them.  Are you in a position to run a test to work it out for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MapInfo User Guide:

[image]

The **CartesianObjectLen( )** function will always return a value using a cartesian 
algorithm. A value of -1 will be returned for data that is in a 
Latitude/Longitude coordinate system, since Latitude/Longitude data is not 
projected and not cartesian.

Comment: MapBasic/MapInfo has also a sphericalObjectLen function which will always calculate the length according to the curved surface. Unless you are working with a non-earth dataset in which case it will return -1